# How to calculate error propagation in spherical astronomy formula?

Tags: error-propagation, spherical-trigonometry

Distance (r) as the angle between two stars are calculated by following formula:
$$
\cos(r) = \sin(\delta_1) \sin(\delta_2) - \cos(\delta_1)\cos(\delta_2)\cos(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)
$$
$\delta$ and $\alpha$ are the sky coordinates of the stars and they have errors as $\Delta \delta_{1,2}$ and $\Delta \alpha_{1,2}$. I want to calculate error in distance ($\Delta r$) by using the errors in coordinates. But I could not find appropriate solution. First I calculated the derivative of this formula;
$$
\begin{align}
-\Delta r \sin(r) =& \Delta \delta_1[\cos(\delta_1)\sin(\delta_2) - \sin(\delta_1)\cos(\delta_2)\cos(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)] \\ +& \Delta \delta_2[\cos(\delta_2)\sin(\delta_1) - \sin(\delta_2)\cos(\delta_1)\cos(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)] \\ -& \Delta(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)\cos(\delta_1)\cos(\delta_2)\sin(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)
\end{align}
$$
but couldn't see the next step. I took $\Delta(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)= \sqrt{\left(\Delta\alpha_1\right)^2 + \left(\Delta\alpha_2\right)^2}$ in here.

Does anyone have knowledge about this?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty just after *Simplification* and *Example*

Comment: @RobertZ, I know these explanations. But in my case, there are many values in the form of product and sum, therefore I could not figure out to form the calculation steps. I am not sure how this should be done, may be it can be like this $s_f = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \delta_1} \right)^{2} (s_{\delta_1})^{2} + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \delta_2} \right)^{2} (s_{\delta_2})^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial (\alpha_1-\alpha_2)} \right)^{2} (s_{\alpha_{1,2}})^{2}}$. But what should the "f" be. It is not clear for me.